# Midnight Commander. Searching current directory

Tags: macos, mc

I am using Midnight Commander on macOS and I can tell it is a lifesaver app. I love how quickly I can navigate through files and folders without a breeze.

Sometimes I need to search for a file in a subdirectory so I navigate through it and use the shortcut ESC + ? to enter the Find File window [image: Find File window] The problem is that the "Start at:" directory is the same as my previous search instead of the current directory.

Is there a way to make the current directory in the active panel the default for this window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there is no such option in MC. As a workaround you may enter `.`  into Find File -> `Start at:` field (i.e. [current directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command))), then next time dialog will use `.` as start directory too.

Also there is `Ctrl + S` quick search for files in current directory, which might be an option in some cases.